# Can I use different brace styles in different projects/solutions in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, formatting, curly-braces

I'm working with a couple of open-source projects that use different C# brace styles, and I'd like to configure VS text formatting to use different styles for each project so I can use Ctrl-K-D to reformat source code.

Is there any way I can configure Visual Studio 2008 to load a particular set of text formatting preferences along with a particular solution file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, there is no way to do this natively in VS 2008 (or even 2010 for that matter)

There is a `resetsettings` [command line switch in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273%28VS.80%29.aspx) which you can use to indicate what settings it should start up with. This works in 2005 and i presume it would with 2008 as well though i have personally not tried it with 2008. If you just make a bat file using this method [as indicated here](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2006/08/25/3995.aspx), that might be one workaround to your problem.

Also, there is an option to do a macro based solutions that might help you that i remember looking at in the past.You can probably [check out this site](http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2007/04/25/111981.aspx) which indicates how to do something very similar to what you are looking for